# std::vector to array in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Is there a way to convert a 2D vector into an array to be able to use it in CUDA kernels?

It is declared as:

```
vector<vector<int>> information;
```

I want to cudaMalloc and copy from host to device, what would be the best way to do it?

```
int *d_information;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_information, sizeof(int)*size);
cudaMemcpy(d_information, information, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no there isn't. The CUDA API doesn't support deep copying and also doesn't know anything about `std::vector` either. If you insist on having a vector of vectors as a host source, it will require doing something like this:

```
int *d_information;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_information, sizeof(int)*size);

int *dst = d_information;
for (std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it = information.begin() ; it != information.end(); ++it) {
    int *src = &((*it)[0]);
    size_t sz = it->size();
    
    cudaMemcpy(dst, src, sizeof(int)*sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dst += sz;
}
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, not compiled or tested. Use at own risk]

This would copy the host memory to an allocation in GPU linear memory, requiring one copy for each vector. If the vector of vectors is a "jagged" array, you will want to store an indexing somewhere for the GPU to use as well.

Comment: Ok, so no way having std::vector in CUDA. Could it be helpful (and easy) to use Thrust? I've never used it before but as far as I read it's somehow similar to the STL library but in CUDA. Any advise?

Comment: No, thrust doesn't have any support for this either. You would be much better off just flattening your host array into a `std::vector<int>` and indexing it as you would linear memory on the device.

Comment: @BRabbit27: I don't know why your edit was rejected, it was correct. I dashed off that code in the browser and when I put that disclaimer in, I really mean it.

Comment: yeah I analyzed what you proposed, I found the mistake and try it on my code and well it worked. I knew the disclaimer was there because you meant it. Anyways, I corrected it use in case someone is interested in something like that but still the disclaimer should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the vector of vectors do not need to reside in a contiguous memory, *i.e.* they can be fragmented.

Depending on the amount of memory you need to transfer I would do one of two issues:

1. Reorder your memory to be a single vector, and then use your `cudaMemcpy`.
2. Create a series of `cudaMemcpyAsync`, where each copy handles a single vector in your vector of vectors, and then synchronize.